# warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi

The segment below is part of a larger function in a larger file.  I have reduced it to what I think are the essentials for explaining my current problem.

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

The line with the call to RegConnectRegistryA is causing the compiler to warn me thusly:  "warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored".  That is the only warning or error in the compiler output.  The build does succeed, and the executable runs as expected.  But I do want to get rid of that warning.  (I think it's been there for many months, to be honest.)

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void whoOpsRegistryGetREG_SZ(
    LPCSTR szServer, 
    LPCSTR szKey, 
    LPCSTR szValue, 
    char* szReturn, 
    int iSize) 
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG WINAPI lReturn = ::RegConnectRegistryA(
        szServer, 
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
        &hKey);
}
```

What I read in other posts leads me to believe that it is somehow related to the #includes.  So here they are.  If you need the contents of any of the header files in quotes, let me know.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <mstask.h>
#include <msterr.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <lm.h>
#include "whoOpsPrivate.h"
#include "whoOps.h"
#include "jni.h"
#include "whoOps_TaskScheduler.h"
#include "whoOps_ServiceMangler.h"
#include "whoOps_RegistryRaptor.h"
#include "../../cyclOps.h"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks to me like the problem is that `WINAPI` is actually a calling convention (IIRC it turns out to mean `stdcall`) so it makes no sense to apply that to the declaration of the variable `lResult`. I don't have a Windows development environment handy to test, but I strongly suspect the warning would go away if you remove `WINAPI`.

Comment: Yay!  That did it.  That's what one gets for using copy-paste inheritence when working in unfamiliar areas.

Comment: More specifically, if I remember correctly, `__stdcall`/`WINAPI` is a replacement for `__pascal` and `__far __pascal`. It's ignored entirely by 64-bit compilers, because the only Windows calling conventions currently available for x64 processors are `__fastcall` (x64) (more commonly known as "the x64 calling convention" or "the MS x64 calling convention"), `__vectorcall` (x64) (MSVC), and `__regcall` (Intel).

Answer (score 3):

It is mostlikely because you are putting WINAPI on the variable declaration of `lReturn`. WINAPI expands to `__stdcall` which specifies a function call convention and has <strike>little</strike> no meaning on variable declarations.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b64e3yk3.aspx) on the warning indicates that using a Microsoft modifier on a data declaration is a dated/anachronistic practice.  If a Microsoft data modifier is being used to modify something on that specific line, my best guess is that it's hidden in either the LONG or WINAPI macro.

I'm not familiar with the Windows API myself, so I can't speak from experience, but...apparently, the WINAPI macro is [defined as __stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28vs.71%29.aspx) [in windef.h](http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/what-is-winapi-macro-164786.html).  Unless you've called that same macro somewhere else without incident, I'd bet that's your culprit.

NM, beaten to it by two people. :p